# How to pass object between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i've an object named **data**.
It is the object of the below given class

```
[DataContract]
public class Details
{
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "values")]
    public values values { get; set; }
}
```

where values is another class with variables.

Now i want to send the object data two another page.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Folder/page2.xaml?object="+ data,UriKind.Relative));
```

and i recieve it as mentioned below

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (e.Uri.OriginalString.Contains("object"))
        {
            string data = NavigationContext.QueryString["object"];
            MessageBox.Show(data); 
        }
    }
```

But while excecuting the above methods, the value stord in **data** variable is

```
Projectname.Foldername.Filename
```

What should i do to pass the object with it's values??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that passing complex object in URI is good idea. My advice is too extend NavigationService class with following code:

```
public static class NavigationExtensions
{

private static object _data= null;

public static void Navigate(this NavigationService service, string page, object data)
{
    _data = data;
    service.Navigate(new Uri(page, UriKind.Relative));
}

public static object GetLastNavigationData(this NavigationService service)
{
    object data = _data;
    _data = null;
    return data;
} }
```

You would call `NavigationService.Navigate("/Folder/page2.xaml", data);` to navigate 
and `var data= NavigationService.GetLastNavigationData()` to get value

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["keyName"] = object;
```

And catch it on the other side in the page.xaml code.

Comment: where shall i use it??while navigating or while recieving on the other page??
Can you please make it clear @Arul?

Comment: Save the data in source page:-

PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["SearchResultList"] = resultData;

Retrieve in destination page :-

List<searchResults> loadedResultData = (List<searchResults>)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["SearchResultList"];